# How to automatically refresh the pivot tables in a protected sheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table, protected

Question: 
I have two worksheets (A & B) within my workbook, each sheet contains several tables and 3 pivot tables. I used the code below to automatically refresh those pivot tables whenever a cell on those tables is clicked/updated. It worked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
PivotTables("001").RefreshTable
PivotTables("002").RefreshTable
PivotTables("003").RefreshTable
End Sub
```

Now,how do I keep the same refresh function after I protect those sheets by password?

To test, I protected **only the worksheet** A by password. 
I then put this code below (found from a forum)in ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Me.Worksheets("A")
    .AllowPivotTable = True
    .Protect Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End With

End Sub
```

After closing the workbook and open it again,
the program shows an error message:

> "run-time error 438, object doesn't support this property or method"

for the line of code `.AllowPivotTable = True`

Could you advise what I should do?
This enabling code does not contain a password. 
Do I need to put a password into the code? 
I read some articles saying it is better to not put password into the code.

Comment: If you password protect the file, then I don't see a way around using it in your code.  However, you can ask for the password and then pass that string to your `.Unprotect Password:=` parameter.  However, if you are doing this every time a cell is clicked/updated that could get very old very quickly!  If you are just password protecting to keep the casual user from messing things up, then you are probably safe to put it into your code.  If you are trying to protect against hacking, that's a whole other volume of questions.

Comment: What forum had `.AllowPivotTable`?

Comment: To reply to BigBen: I got that code from the first answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/07d08bc3-7b0c-4f14-8b14-7a4f23eba2b0/excel-2010-can-i-refresh-pivot-table-on-protected-sheet?forum=excel

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation and this is how I resolved.

I had 3 sheets named sickLevae,Summary 1 and summary 2. Sick leave contains main data and summary 1 and 2 contains pivot table, so below is the code that I tried and it works fine.

Please try this way:

```
Sub RefreshPtInSummary1()

    Call RefreshPivotTables(shtSummary1)

End Sub

Sub RefreshPtInSummary2()

    Call RefreshPivotTables(shtSummary2)

End Sub

Sub RefreshPivotTables(sht As Worksheet)

    Dim pt As pivotTable

    shtSummary1.Unprotect g_sPassword
    shtSummary2.Unprotect g_sPassword
    For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
        Exit For
    Next pt
    shtSummary1.Protect g_sPassword
    shtSummary2.Protect g_sPassword
    MsgBox "Pivot Table Updated"

End Sub
```